# CDF and PDF relationship

Tags: statistics

I am given the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$.
(a) Calculate the expected value and the variance of $X$.

(b) Find the probability density function of $Y=X^2$.

For part a), am I supposed to find the derivatives of $F(x)$ on each interval and then calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) \,dx$?

For part b), can someone please give me some clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finding the derivative and then integrating would work if you have a continuous distribution, so if you use this approach then you should check this

Comment: For (b) one approach is to say that $\Pr(Y \le y)=\Pr(-\sqrt y \le X \le \sqrt y)$ when $y \ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

**Part A:**  Yes, since there are no step-discontinuities (indicating massive points), you can find the probability density function by derivation in each part.$$f_{\small X}(x)=\tfrac 12\begin{cases}\mathrm d \mathrm e^x/\mathrm d x&:&x\lt 0\\\mathrm d 1/\mathrm d x&:& 0\leqslant x\lt 1\\\mathrm d(2-\mathrm e^{(1-x)/2})/\mathrm d x&:& 1\leqslant x \end{cases}$$

Then you simply integrate $x^n\,f_{\small X}(x)$ over each part as needed. $$\mathsf E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^0 \tfrac x2\tfrac{\mathrm d\mathrm e^x}{\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d x+\int_0^1\tfrac x2\tfrac{\mathrm d 1}{\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d x+\int_1^\infty\tfrac x2\tfrac{\mathrm d (2-\mathrm e^{(1-x)/2})}{\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d x$$

$$\mathsf {Var}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^0 \tfrac {x^2}2\tfrac{\mathrm d\mathrm e^x}{\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d x+\int_0^1\tfrac {x^2}2\tfrac{\mathrm d 1}{\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d x+\int_1^\infty\tfrac {x^2}2\tfrac{\mathrm d (2-\mathrm e^{(1-x)/2})}{\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d x - \mathsf E(X)^2$$

**Part B:** Use the Jacobian transformation (orthe chain rule of derivation).  Notice, because the support for $X^2$ will be $[0..\infty)$, therefore it will be most useful to consider this as $[0..1)\cup[1..\infty)$.

$$\begin{align}F_{\small X^2}(y)&=F_{\small X}(\surd y)-F_{\small X}(\surd y)\\[3ex]f_{\small X^2}(y) &= \dfrac{f_{\small X}(\surd y)+f_{\small X}(-\surd y)}{2\surd y}\mathbf 1_{(0\leqslant y\lt 1)\cup(1\leqslant y)}\end{align}$$